# Cisco ASA not passing traffic between two interface

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, network, security

I have Cisco 5506 with Security Plue License and following is my configuration.

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif eng
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.11.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

Now i have connect two PC in each interface to test ping between two LAN but i am not able to ping.

I have configured following option also but still they are not able to ping.

`same-security-traffic permit inter-interface`

Do i need to configure NAT rules for these two LAN to exempt from NAT, following is my NAT rules.

```
nat (any,outside) after-auto source dynamic NET-PRIVATE-SUBNETS interface
```

My object group

```
object-group network NET-PRIVATE-SUBNETS
   network-object 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0
   network-object 10.0.11.0 255.255.255.0
```

what i am missing to make them pingable between two LAN?

Comment: Have you tried using packet-tracer to simulate the traffic and see where it stops?

Comment: I found Cisco anyconnect vpn was using 10.11.0.0 pool for VPN client, i didn't realized. I think we should delete this question or close. sorry for trouble.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense then.

Comment: The quickest way to stop this question from staying active is to just add an answer and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been fix, found someone configured 10.11.0.0 in anyconnect VPN pool so in short subnet duplication issue.